# Laravel Mail: Markdown Email [ Class "Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content" not found ]

Tags: laravel

I am getting a super strange error when I am creating a markdown email with Laravel.

I have a simple Markdown email (code below), the issue is with line 43 at "return new Content("

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use App\Models\User;


class RegisteredUser extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    protected $user;


    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function content()
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'users.register.new',
            with: [
                'name' => $this->name,
            ],
        );
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->content();
        // return $this->markdown('users.register.new');
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

`local.ERROR: Class "Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content" not found {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailables\\Content\" not found at www/app/Mail/RegisteredUser.php:43)`

How is that possible? Shouldn't that be included with Laravel 9? (9.19)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the syntax I am using was introduced in Laravel 9.3 so I had to update Laravel using:

composer update.

PS. I was able to solve this from the help of Laravel's official discord group. Thank you <3

Comment: Also, if you have already run `composer update` to Laravel 10+ and your Intelliphense is still complaining about Envelope / Content being missing, close & re-open the IDE (VSCode etc.)